# Jump to previous index and continue the loop

Tags: java, foreach

I have a for-each loop and I am trying to create branching based on conditions. It currently will hit a request to branch to an index, it does that and then leaves the loop. What I am trying to do is go to an earlier index and carry on in the for-each loop.

The assignment is to create a stack based assembly reader in Java. I have tried a standard for loop and a for each loop setting the index to an earlier index and the result is the same.

```
for(Item i : items) {
    if (i == someValue) {
        i = someIndex;
    }
}
```

So if the loop indexes take a number (starting at 0) compare it to a target value (say 5) and if it is not equal then i = the beginning of the loop. Once the value is 5 it then continues.

Comment: "*What I am trying to do is go to an earlier index and carry on in the for-each loop.*" - Not possible with `foreach`. Use a regular loop instead. This smells like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Care to explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you very much. I had tried this before, but I must have been missing something.

Comment: Instead of appending `[solved]` to the question title, do one of: 1) Accept an answer that has the solution. 2) Create an answer yourself if one doesn't exist, and accept it *(if you think others might benefit from such answer)*. 3) **Delete the question** by clicking the `delete` link below the question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Each loop is not what you want when you have to deal with indexes.
Standard For, modifying your index withing the loop is the way to go:

> So if the loop indexes take a number (starting at 0) compare it to a
>   target value (say 5) and if it is not equal then i = the beginning of
>   the loop. Once the value is 5 it then continues.

```
 //define someValue
 //define someIndex
for(i=0;i<=items.length-1;) { //notice i didn't use the i++ sentence in the for definition
    if (i == someValue) {
        i++; //continue
     } else {
        i=0; //go to the beginning
     }
}
```